# Converting t3a.medium to t4g.medium EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to convert t3a.medium to t4g.medium instance getting below error.

```
't4g.medium' is not a valid instance type for instance 'i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' of architecture 'x86_64'
```

Is there any way to find the right instance type? I did some research but not found anything related, no reply from the AWS support form.

I want to convert all my t3a and t3 type instances to the t4g type instance, any clue to fix this problem will be really helpful.

Comment: You would need to rebuild the instance from scratch because the operating system has been built for a different type of processor.

Answer (score 3):

The error means that the AMI's CPU architecture you're using is 64-bit(x86) but you selected 64-bit(Arm) for converting.

You can search arm64 type instances in Console -> EC2 -> Instance type.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I understood the error the reason. so the direct conversion is not possible I need to rebuild new and transfer data manually, right?

Comment: you do not need to manually transfer the data, just detach the EBS and re attache it to the new EC2 instance.

Comment: @AmithJayasekara - you're assuming the data lives on a separate volume.

Comment: no, you can even detach  the root volume if the instance is stopped and the volume is an EBS  , ( https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/detach-volume.html )

Comment: @AmithJayasekara Yes you can technically attach the root volume, but since all the binaries will be in amd64, it will not work when you try to boot the instance under an arm architecture.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible or allowed to change the t3 series to the t4g series because both series architecture is different.

- t3 series architecture  - x86_64
- t4g series architecture - arm64

To resolve this issue, first create a new t4g series server and then transfer data from your t3 series to the t4g series